# Adding title in a tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Can you please help me adding title in my tabbed pane? There is no title in tabbed pane even I declared.

I am creating a Frame that will have tabbed pane inside of it the tabbed pane do have panel inside of it the problem that I encountered is that I cannot add name in my tabbed pane even I use the correct method for it.

I have already tried `tabbedPane.add()`, `tabbedPane.addTab()`, `tabbedPane.insertTab()` but none of this insert title in my tab pane.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("This is first tab");


    tabbedPane.addTab("Panel 1",panel1);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Panel 2",panel2);

    lb1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel1.add(lb1);
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tabbedPane.setSize(1000,600);
    f.add(tabbedPane);
    tabbedPane.add(panel1);
    tabbedPane.add(panel2);
    f.setBounds(10,20,1200,800);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.setVisible(true);
```

I am expecting that there will be a title on my tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("This is first tab");

tabbedPane.addTab("Panel 1", panel1);
tabbedPane.addTab("Panel 2", panel2);

//lb1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
panel1.add(lb1);
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//tabbedPane.setSize(1000, 600);
f.add(tabbedPane);
//tabbedPane.add(panel1);
//tabbedPane.add(panel2);
f.setBounds(10, 20, 1200, 800);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

f.setVisible(true);
```

I don't know why you are:

- Setting the layout of a `JLabel`
- Adding the panel's to the `tabbedPane` again

Adding a component to a container will first remove it from it's parent, which is probably why the titles are no longer appearing

Comment: Thank you so much I fixed my problem, this is just a prototype  I am just trying to test the function of tabpane. Anyway thank you so much